# MSBUILD publish does not publish a xsd schema file

Tags: msbuild, web-services

I am using MSbuild to publish my webservices projects on the command line using the following
command:

> msbuild.exe MyWebservicesProjectPath\Services.csproj /t:ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication /p:Configuration=Release;BuildingProject=true;WebProjectOutputDir=c:\inetpub\wwwroot\webserviceDest;OutDir=c:\inetpub\wwwroot\webserviceDest\

Everything publishes fine except for .xsd files that are located in ProjectName\WebServices\Schema folder.
what's happening here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your solution check the property of your .xsd file.

The default setting of this type of artifact for the **"Copy to Output Directory"** is **"Do Not Copy"**.

Setting this to **"Copy always"** (or "Copy if newer") should fix your problem.

**Project file sample**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="XMLSchema1.xsd">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the solution explorer right click on .XSD file -> click Properties and change Build Action to "Content" under Advanced section.